# OpenCL acceleration with gographics/imagick

Tags: go, imagemagick, opencl, gpu, imagick

I have been putting enormous effort trying to get GPU acceleration for my Imagemagick resize operations using Go and its imagick library: https://gopkg.in/gographics/imagick.v2/imagick

I have built imagemagick with OpenCL support and OpenCL acceleration works perfectly well when used in command line. However when using the resize operation in my Go code using imagick, no GPU acceleration happens. I have verified this through performance tests.

I have also tried modifying the imagick library in my own fork by adding support for explicitly initializing OpenCL (InitImageMagickOpenCL) but this provided no solution whatsoever.

I'd really appreciate if someone had a solution to this issue.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just two ideas: (1) check whether the imagick library the Go code uses is really the one you compiled and (2) if all else fails and you are sure you have done everything correctly, [raise an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/gographics/imagick/), maybe they can help you directly.

Comment: I raised an issue in GitHub. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Any help is still welcome :)